# JMeter - Timer and list variable

Tags: jmeter

I have the following setup in my Test Plan.

```
Thread Group (number of thread = 1)
    ForEach controller
        Precise Througput Timer
        POST request

Teardown Thread Group
    ForEach controller
        DELETE request
```

I have the following two questions that I could not find answer for. I'd appreciate if someone can help me with.

1. My understanding is that the `Precise Throughput Timer` under `ForEach controller` in `Thread Group` schedules the POST requests to be sent so that the desired throughput is achieved. However, I am confused because the `POST request` is in a loop, which I expect that the a request in the next iteration can only be sent if the request in the current iteration is finished, i.e. getting back a response. If the current request is taking a long time to finish, does it mean it changes the time the next request is sent and thus affects the throughput? Or is the next request being sent without waiting for the current request to finish to ensure the defined schedule (made by the `Precise Throughput Timer`) is maintained?
2. I need to save the resource ID returned from the POST request (if the POST request is successful) to a variable to a list and later in the `Teardown Thread Group` I can loop through these IDs. I could not find yet any list type variable in JMeter that allows me to do that. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

2. Unfortunately can't use variables for transmission between threads. 
   Need use property:

Set property `props.put("resourceID", "qwerty");`

Get property `${__property(resourceID)}`

Comment: Does it mean that the next iteration override the value saved by the current iteration, `props.put("resourceID", "whatever-value")` replaces the currently saved value of `resourceID` by `whatever-value`?